Application of algebraic topology to set theory
Reading this thread:
Applications of $\sf ZFC$/Set Theory in algebraic topology,
I asked myself the opposite question. Since there is many applications of Algebraic Topology in many fields of maths (it is hard to think of one without any application, unless this one), is there at least one significant application of Algebraic Topology in pure Set Theory?
